# Magento under XAMPP very slow

Tags: xampp

I installed Magento 2.0.2 (latest) locally under XAMPP on Windows10 for developing purposes and it is very slow in admin interface.

Working on hardware: SSD, 16GB RAM, i7 CPU, 
PHP ver. 5.6.8 - should I upgrade on PHP7?

Anybody know why its happenning ?

In configuration of Magento I can see there is
 Full-page Cache with options **Built-in Application**(default) or **Varnish Caching**,
should I install Varnish?

And Storage Configuration for Media
Media Storage **File System**(default) or **Database** - Which option is faster please?

Comment: have the same problem. You solved it???

Comment: This is not in case of magento only. This is due to mysql issues in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use PHP7 and if you can use a Linux machine, a virtual machive with VirtualBox is good enough.

Comment: thx, ill try PHP7 under XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

I ran Magentos on XAMPP since a long time on a powerfull computer (250g ssd, 12gb ram, win 7 pro).
I tried many config improvements we can easily find on the internet without any big effect.

Finally, for my case, the change that increased dramatically the performance was: switch off the antivirus realtime scan (or add exclusion for XAMPP folders).

Note: don't forget to restart the computer after the antivirus setting update (without that, the change couldn't take effect properly).

Comment: This also helped me a lot, the real time scanner on my computer was slowing down things a lot.

Comment: i have 8gb ram & 250gb ssd , celeron processor in xampp. magento is not running fast